# Google Analytics - Do I track an info popup as pageview or event

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, tracking

I have some popups on my page that provide that can be opened by the user to get more information.

Should I track them as page view or as events? Whats the right way to go here?

Comment: What type of popup is it?  Is it a lightbox or div that floats on top of the current page, or is it a new browser window?

Answer (score 1):

If it is an actual popup, you track the 2 separately.

The event is the launching / opening of the popup.

Once it's loaded, track it as a pageview.